# Want to save objects with specfic chars only removing the chars which is not found in char list

Tags: c#

Trying to save the object with the available chars only!

```
 string name = "<Matias><Andres>";
 char[] list = {'m', 'a', 't', 'i', 's', 'n', 'd', 'r', 'e'};

 databaseObject objects = new databaseObject();
 objects.set("name", ???);
```

For example i dont have < and > in chars so i dont want that in output.
so that the output would look like matias andres

Comment: What have you tried?  What specifically is not working?

Comment: Think about `string name` as an array of `char` that you can loop through. Maybe that will set you in the right direction. But if you show what you've tried, it would be better.

Comment: Already found an solution :) , Thank you!